# Song from end credits of Escape From Pretoria video

Tags: identify-this-song, soundtrack, identify-this-genre

*https://youtu.be/0WyeAaYjlxE?t=46m52s*

I am trying to identify both the specific title and genre of the song played at the end of the "Escape From Pretoria" video starting around 46:52.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the specific title, but the genre is traditional South African acapella choral music.

This sounds quite a bit like the group Ladysmith Black Mambazo, the best internationally known exponent of this style.  They initially became famous outside South Africa when they collaborated with Paul Simon for several songs off his 1986 hit album, *Graceland*.  If you do a search for their music, you'll find a wealth of songs in this genre.

Comment: @Bebs It doesn't answer the title, but it does answer the genre.

Answer (score 1):

It is [Free South Africa](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B07MR576B2/ref=dm_ws_tlw_trk17) by French songwriter Pascal Danae